# Angular's $log.debug() not showing on Chrome's console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

Recently my Chrome Browser stopped showing `$log.debug()` messagens on console. I have been using this way of logging with angular, instead of `console.log()`, across all my controllers because it is easy to disable logging when I upload my scripts to production servers.

I have already checked my `$logProvider` configuration and `debugEnabled()` is set to `true`.

For some reason the only way of showing `$log.debug()` messages on chrome is enabling `verbose` messages on console filter. Until recently that was not necessary. Enabling verbose isn't nice, since console spits lots of other messages that I don't care about.

I'm currently using Chrome v60.0.3112.101 64 bits on a Windows 7 machine. Is it related to browser's version? Can I do something to make it show messages again without verbose mode?

Ps.: Firefox continues showing everything as always.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`console.debug` log level is inconsistent between Chrome/Chromium versions. Console UI was changed in [Chrome 58](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/03/devtools-release-notes). Currently `console.debug` requires **verbose** level.

If other console entries are unwanted at this log level, console settings can be changed to **User messages only**:

[image: console.debug]

If this behaviour should be changed within particular page, `console` can be patched:

```
console.debug = console.log;
```

Considering that AngularJS `$log` service is an abstraction over `console`, and `$log.debug` was made dependent on `debugEnabled` state to distinguish it from `$log.log`, this can be fixed in less obtrusive manner in AngularJS application:

```
app
.config(['$provide', '$logProvider', ($provide, $logProvider) => {
  // expose a provider to reach debugEnabled in $log
  $provide.value('$logProvider', $logProvider);
})
.decorator('$log', ['$logProvider', '$delegate', ($logProvider, $delegate) => {
  // override $log.debug
  $delegate.debug = function () {
    if (!$logProvider.debugEnabled())
      return;
    $delegate.log.apply($delegate, arguments);
  }

  return $delegate;
}]);
```

Comment: I haven't tried the decorator option, Tested the "User messagens only" and worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. 'User messages only' will remove all other entries that have higher log level but don't result from `console` calls (e.g. failed requests). This may be undesirable.

Comment: The decorator code didn't work for me, but just learning how Chrome hides logs really helped!